# Parsley working slowly and giving error uncaught syntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm using parsley.js to validate my form and I'm using on `form:success` event. When I don't use the event it works fine and it works really fast, but when I use the event I have this error.

[image]

Normally when I fill all the fields in the form but leave one, it works fine but when I fill all the fields the error reoccurs. It doesn't depend on one field any field left out works fine.

This is my code.

```js
 SubmitSectionForm: function (obj, context) {
  var form          = $('div#step-' + context.fromStep + ' form');
  var AjaxURL       = form.attr('action');
  var formData      = form.serialize();
  var shouldSave    = form.find('[name=should_save]').val();
  var SmartWizard   = this;
  var isSaveAndExit = !!context.toStep;

  // Validate form  
  form.parsley().on('form:success', function () {
   if (shouldSave == 'true') {
    NProgress.start();

    $.post(AjaxURL, formData, function (response) {
     if (response && !response.errors) {
      SmartWizard.goForward();
     } else {
      var errorDiv = $('div.alert-danger');
      var errorsHTML = '';

      $.each(response.errors, function (i) {
       errorsHTML += '<li>' + response.errors[i] + '</li>';
      });

      errorDiv.find('ul').html(errorsHTML);
      errorDiv.removeClass('hidden');

      errorDiv.delay(10000).queue(function () {
       $(this).addClass('hidden').dequeue();
      });
     }
    }).always(function () {
     NProgress.done();
    });
   }

   if (!isSaveAndExit) {
    window.location = '/';
   } else {
    SmartWizard.goForward();
   }
  }).validate();
 },
```

Comment: pause on exceptions in dev tools and see what is going on...

Comment: Please how do I do that?

Comment: *Please* post your code as text, NOT an image. Thanks.

Comment: @samiles Okay sure

Comment: @samiles done with changing codes.

Comment: I think we should have the HTML DOM too since it might be related to a regex there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the latest version of `parsley`. The latest `_actualize` does not call `off`.
Also, which version of jQuery are you using?
BTW, you should develop with the non minimized version of parsley.